# How can I Print a clickable text in python, which go to a URL

Tags: python, url, hyperlink

I would like to print a text using python [ on pycharm terminal ] with a URL. Can any one suggest how can I do that.

```
`url = https://stackoverflow.com/.com
print ("Click me")`
```

I am expecting the text "[Click me](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)" to be printed as a clickable text, which can go to https://stackoverflow.com/.com

Comment: Any text in a terminal program is plain text, unless the terminal program has specific support for identifying a URL and making it clickable. Either way it is not up to your Python script to make it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
.com/.com
```

to:

```
.com/
```

Does this will help?

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("WebBrowsers")

root.geometry("640x480")

webbrowser.open("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: Just execute it and will take you to website right now.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** possibilites to open a hyperlink.

**1. Open with the standard terminal:**

Here you can not influence the click feature by Python code.
To open a link in the Terminal just `print()` the link with Python to the Terminal with Stdout and use `Ctrl` + `Left-Click` to open the link.

```
print("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

**2. Use a GUI Framework to design a click button:**

This is the recommend way to design such a click feature, because of the better  ergonomics.

To design a simple GUI, I recommend using `tkinter`, especially in the beginning.

You can then simply implement your button and make it clickable by applying an event to it. To open the link you can simply use the `webbrowser` module and call the `webbrowser.open()` function.

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

window = Tk()

def onClick():
    webbrowser.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com") # Opening the URL

button = Button(window, text="Click me!", command=onClick) # Assigning button and adding the click event.
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the information. I have managed to receive the URL in markup text to my communicator as notification.